# Displaying all substrings of some given string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

I solved exercise 8 from *Core Java for Impatient*, chapter 1. This exercise is to implement a `displayAllCombinations` method to display all substrings of the given string.

I would like to prove that following algorithm is valid in Java. I wonder if there is an easier solution?

```
package pl.hubot.exercises.corejava.r01.ex08;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This program contains mine solutions of exercises
 * from book Core Java for the Impatient, chapter 1.
 *
 * The content of following exercise:
 * "Write a program that reads a string and displays all contained
 * in it non-empty strings."
 *
 * @version 1.00 23-07-2016
 * @author Hubot
 */
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter any string: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = in.nextLine();
        displayAllCombinations(text);
    }

    private static void displayAllCombinations(String text)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int ending = text.length();
        while (offset != ending)
        {
            String result = text.substring(current, ending - offset);
            if (!result.equals(""))
                System.out.println(result);
            if (current != (ending - offset)) current++;
            else
            {
                current = 0;
                offset++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run:

> ```
> Enter any string: Amy
> Amy
> my
> y
> Am
> m
> A
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable names `offset`, `current`, and `ending` could be better.  `offset` seems to be distance from the end, and `current` acts as a starting index, so the names should reflect that.

The loop logic is cryptic.  There is a `current = 0; offset++;` that "resets" the loop, so it would be more clearly written with nested `for` loops instead.

If you do it right, you shouldn't need to check `!result.equals("")`.  If you did need to check, then it would be better written as `!result.isEmpty()`.

```
private static void displayAllCombinations(String text) {
    for (int end = text.length(); end > 0; end--) {
        for (int start = 0; start < end; start++) {
            System.out.println(text.substring(start, end));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (!result.equals(""))
            System.out.println(result);
        if (current != (ending - offset)) current++;
        else
        {
            current = 0;
            offset++;
        }
```

This is hard to read. On one occasion you've opted for no braces, same line, on another occasion you opted for no braces, multi-line, and later again you go for braces, multi-line.

Be consistent with the placement of your braces. It makes it easier to read the code.

```
    while (offset != ending)
    {
        String result = text.substring(current, ending - offset);
        if (!result.equals("")) 
        {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        if (current != (ending - offset)) 
        {
            current++;
        }
        else
        {
            current = 0;
            offset++;
        }
    }
```

Beyond that, this program seems trivial and there's not much else to say about it.

There are, of course, various minor improvements we could make, such as...

- Storing `ending - offset` in a variable called `endIndex` and calling current `beginIndex` to match `substring`'s argument names
- Rewriting the handling of `beginIndex` (current):

  ```
  beginIndex++;
  if (beginIndex== endIndex) 
  {
      beginIndex = 0;
      offset++;
  }
  ```

  This gets rid of the empty string case, whilst also simplifying your if-else statement.
- Then, since we no longer need to check if the substring is an empty string, we just print the substring directly.

Such improvements would leave you with a result like so:

```
private static void displayAllCombinations(String text)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int beginIndex = 0;
    int ending = text.length();
    while (offset != ending)
    {
        int endIndex = ending - offset;
        System.out.println(text.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
        beginIndex++;
        if (beginIndex == endIndex) 
        {
            beginIndex = 0;
            offset++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for testing its correctness, I'd use unit tests, and instead of printing to screen, you add the strings to a `List` and return the list. Interesting cases are empty string, single character string, and a regular string like "Amy".

Comment: nitpick, in Java they use egyptian braces

Comment: @DanPantry I'm just copying his style

Answer (score 0):

I know its kind of a late response but still if anybody finds it helpful.

I would like to suggest a slightly different approach, not much of a performance improvement but much easier to read.

---

This approach uses recursion. We just take a character out of the string one at a time, and every character have two choices :-

- Either it does not want to be part of the solution or
- It wants to be part of the solution.

so here's the code.

```
    public static void printSS(String ques, String ans) {
    if (ques.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(ans);
        return;
    }
    char ch = ques.charAt(0);
    String restOfTheString = ques.substring(1);

    // char does not want to be part of the solution
    printSS(restOfTheString, ans + "");

    // char wants to be part of the solution
    printSS(restOfTheString, ans + ch);
}
```

And if you want to follow [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), here's a slightly different solution which returns an ArrayList of all possible compinations :-

```
public static ArrayList<String> getSS(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        ArrayList<String> baseResult = new ArrayList<>();
        baseResult.add("");
        return baseResult;
    }

    char ch = str.charAt(0);
    String ros = str.substring(1);

    ArrayList<String> recursionResult = getSS(ros);
    ArrayList<String> myResult = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < recursionResult.size(); i++) {
        myResult.add("" + recursionResult.get(i)); // ch says no
        myResult.add(ch + recursionResult.get(i)); // ch says yes
    }
    return myResult;
}
```